# Where can I find Vessel save games?

Tags: vessel

I'm playing the Steam version of the game, which doesn't appear to use Steam Cloud. I found `steamapps\common\vessel\Data\Save Games` after poking around, but it doesn't appear to contain the save files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 7 (and presumably Vista too) I found the save games in `%AppData%\Vessel`, which contains the `.sav` save game files.